# Counting occurrences of a value in a column of a table - postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with multiple columns:

```
table1 | column1 | column2 | column3 |
       |    x    |  ....   |   ....  |
       |    y    |  ....   |   ....  |
       |    x    |  ....   |   ....  |
```

How can I count the occurences of a value, for example x, in one of the columns, for example column1? Given table1 this would have to return me 2 (numbers of x present in column1).

Comment: You should really find a tutorial on SQL. This is basic information that isn't different for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE column1 = 'x'
```

Comment: I'm new to sql/postgresql. Thanks, mate!

Answer (score 23):

You can use `SUM()` aggregate function with a `CASE` statement like

```
select sum(case when column1 = 'x' then 1 else 0 end) as X_Count
from tabl1;
```

Comment: Is this faster than the buildin fucntion count()?

Comment: @VictorTurrisi, It should and must give you same performance as with count(). It just a different way of doing the same problem.

Comment: If the table is significant in size, and there's an index on column1, then using the WHERE condition will potentially be a big win, since it will only access columns that match the condition (and in fact, might not hit the table at all, for this simple case, satisfying the answer from the index), whereas  your logic in the return set will force a ful-table scan every time.

Comment: This is also nice because it let's you count values in the same column many times (e.g. count occurrences of x in the column, occurrences of y, etc), good answer!

Comment: The advantage of using `sum` is, that you can calculate more than one sum per `select`, whereas `count` counts all results of the `select`.

Comment: Another advantage over `count(*)` is that you will get an explicit 0 for groups where not all criteria were met, rather than the group being omitted from the result. Eg where `select gcol, count(*) from tbl where wcol = 'foo' group by gcol` won't have any row where `wcol` wasn't 'foo', while `select sum(case when wcol = 'foo' then 1 else 0 end) from tbl group by gcol` will have a row for all distinct `gcol` values. Probably obvious... but I wound up here because I wanted the 0 and `count` wasn't giving it to me.